# What is internal generated voltage of synchronous motor?

Tags: power, motor, synchronous

A 208-V Y-connected synchronous motor is drawing 40 A at unity power factor from a 208-V power system. The field current flowing under these conditions is 2.7 A. Its synchronous reactance is 0.8 Ω. Assume a linear open-circuit characteristic.

The answer is given as:

[image]

However, I do not understand where they got that equation for E<sub>A</sub>. I was under the impression that the equation for the phase voltage is:

[image]

Wouldn't this mean that the equation for the internal generated voltage is E<sub>A</sub> = V<sub>Φ</sub> + jX<sub>s</sub>I<sub>A</sub>?

**EDIT:**
My bad. That's the equation for a synchronous generator, not a synchronous motor.

This is the equation for a synchronous motor:
[image]

Comment: TRy again.............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you supply mechanical power to a synchronous machine, it becomes a synchronous generator generating electrical power.

Electrical power converts the synchronous machine into a motor providing mechanical power.

From [Electric Machinery Fundamentals](https://www.academia.edu/16855362/Electric_Machinery_Fundamentals_5th_Edition_By_Chapman). As a motor:

[image: Synchronous motor]

$$V_{\phi} = E_A + j I_A X_S + I_A R_A$$ 
As a generator:
[image: Synchronous Generator]

$$V_{\phi} = E_A - j I_A X_S - I_A R_A$$

Note direction of current.  The voltage seen at the terminals \$V_{\phi}\$ will depend on 
whether the synchronous machine takes current or generates current, hence the change of signs.  Just Kirchhoff's Voltage Law.